# How to Create different kinds of grid lines using D3 in the same graph

Tags: d3.js, graph, grid

I am using D3 to generate the graph in an angular 5 project. I have a requirement to generate the graph as shown in required attachment. It has both solid and dashed grid lines in the same graph. I am not sure how I can achieve it.

Can anyone please help me to fix it ? Please find the actual and required graphs

1. Image 1  - Actual
2. Image 2  - Required

[image: Actual]
[image: Required]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can look at this example to add Minor ticks and Major ticks.
https://bl.ocks.org/erikvullings/41be28677574fd484b43e91413a7e45d

you can use the attribute stroke-dasharray to create dashed lines. It depends on the structure of your svg, but you can select the lines and add this attribute.

example:

```
d3.selectAll("g.tick line").attr("stroke-dasharray", "5 5")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your valuable time to respond !

Comment: I created a sample application like mentioned in the above link and it worked. But I am using D3 version 3. Looks like it does not work with Version 3. The minor tickets does not appear at all.. Can you please suggest ?